# How can I prevent scrolling when using slideToggle() to show an previous div?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have a footer with some hidden divs and links, which should should show the divs when clicking not them:

```
<div class="rvc-footer">

  <div id="block1" class="rvc-footer-block">
    Block1
  </div>
  <div id="block2" class="rvc-footer-block">
    Block 2
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="footer-button" href="#block1">Block1</a>
    <a class="footer-button" href="#block2">Block2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

When using

```
// On clicking of the links do something.
link.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var a = $(this).attr("href");
  $(a).slideToggle();
});
```

to show the div, the content scrolls down and the link is not visible any more (when the link was at the bottom of the browser). Is there a way to force the browser to stay at the link position.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luxio/nammg2b0/)

Comment: Do you mean that the `body` need to scroll down after the animation was finished?

Comment: @MoshFeu The div is before the trigger link, I want the link not to move at all. So maybe I have to scroll down the body simultaneously why the appearing div.

Comment: `I want the link not to move at all` The link will move because of the `div`. If you want I can show you how to scroll to the bottom of the `body` after the animation was over.

Comment: @MoshFeu Thanks, I would like to see your idea.

Answer (score 0):

After the animation of `$(a).slideToggle();` ended, you can animate the `scrollTop` of `html, body` to the top offset of the buttons div `.footer-button-wrapper`.

```js
// Get all the links.
var link = $("a.footer-button");

console.log(link);

// On clicking of the links do something.
link.on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var a = $(this).attr("href");
  console.log(a);
  $(".rvc-footer-block").not(a).slideUp();
  //$(a).slideToggle(function(){
  //  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.footer-button-wrapper').offset().top }, 600);
  //});

  $(a).animate({
    height: 'toggle'
  },
               {
    step: function () {
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.footer-button-wrapper').offset().top }, 0);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.rvc-footer {
  margin-top: 1000px;
}

.footer-button-wrapper {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.rvc-footer-block {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.footer-button-wrapper .footer-button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rvc-footer">
  <div id="block1" class="rvc-footer-block">
    <h2>
      Block1
    </h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
  </div>
  <div id="block2" class="rvc-footer-block">
    <h2>
      Block2
    </h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
  </div>
  <div id="block3" class="rvc-footer-block">
    <h2>
      Block3
    </h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
  </div>
  <div class="footer-button-wrapper">
    <a class="footer-button" href="#block1">Block1</a>
    <a class="footer-button" href="#block2">Block2</a>
    <a class="footer-button" href="#block3">Block3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This will work ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luxio/v8mo2ct4/)). I would prefer, if the footer-buttons would not move at all in the browser during the toggle.

Comment: I was updated my answer.. Notice that this solution make the body "shake". It's the best you can do. If you to avoid this, you have to set the all `div`s the same height. Maybe add `overflow:scroll` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
// On clicking of the links do something.
link.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var a = $(this).attr("href");
  $(a).slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: What should  `e.stopPropagation();` prevent?

Comment: @Stéphane Kills the bubbling on the click event.

Comment: but it does not prevent the links moving downwards.